# "How many language do you speak?" OR "How many language you speak?"

Tags: subordinate-clauses, interrogatives, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> How many language do you speak?

OR

> How many language you speak?

Which one is correct?  What is the difference?

I have found another example:

> How much food are you going to take with yourselves?

OR

> How much food you are going to take with yourselves?`

Comment: All four are incorrect.  It should be plural _languages_, not singular. And _Do_-Support is required in a yes-no question with no auxiliary verb. The second pair should have _with you_ instead of _with yourselves_, and Subject-Auxiliary Inversion is required in real questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a WH-question where the question word is not the subject, we always put the auxiliary before the subject, introducing a form of *do* as auxiliary if there isn't already one.

So:

> How many languages do you speak?

In very informal speech, the auxiliary (*do*, *are* etc) is sometimes inaudible, or very nearly so; but in more careful speech it is always there.

A point you didn't ask about: *language* is a count noun, so you appropriately used *how many* rather than *how much*. But *how many* is always followed by a plural: *how many languages*, not *how many language*.

Answer (score -2):

I think the first  one is correct because in the second on their has no verb.. Do is the verb of these sentences. in second sentence main verb is absence.